# When i compile my code getting error like (Expected token Semicolon got 'LParen')

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20

I am using remix ide solidity compiler version is 0.4.21 while creating erc20 token im getting the error
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Try to avoid images with code in the future, just copy and paste the relevant parts, is easy for people trying to help and therefore you are more likely to get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you say you are using 0.4.21 this error appears when you use a compiler older than `:0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c.Emscripten.clang` because the emit keyword was not introduced.

Use the provided version or newer and the error will disappear.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Im also tried 0.4.24 but no use getting the same error

Comment: please post your code

Comment: working good bro thanks for your ans its very helpful